# Is there a way to sort apps in Google's app store by size?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to sort apps in Google's app store by size? I would like to know what are the heaviest apps and the lightest apps from a search result. For example, to search for a lightweight RSS reader.

Comment: www.appbrain.com allows sorting via more options than the Play store, but size isn't a criterion unfortunately for your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any third-party app or site that does this. I did look around a few months ago and found nothing, but something might have come up since then.

However, if the reason you're looking for this feature is because of limited app space, AppBrain (both the app and the website) has a feature to view only apps with App2SD enabled.