# How to view bargain sales on Play Store ordered by discount or category

Tags: google-play-store

Before this is marked as duplicate, here are related questions but NOT dealing with this question

1. [Is there a way to sort apps in Google's app store by size?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21586/is-there-a-way-to-sort-apps-in-googles-app-store-by-size)
2. [Is there a way to sort apps by popularity (number of 'downloads') in the Google Play Store, or otherwise?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55772/is-there-a-way-to-sort-apps-by-popularity-number-of-downloads-in-the-google)

---

I prefer to manually update play store apps periodically. Yesterday, while doing this, I found a couple of apps which were purchased about a year ago at steep discounts, in one case a $9 app is now priced at $5 and in another $2 app priced at 20 cents.

This set me searching for more discounted apps on Play Store, which are not listed separately as discounted but included in "Top Paid". Further, there is no way of filtering discounted apps, or by discount percentage

Couldn't locate any app to do this and further search led me to this [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets) to see if any other app could do this.

[Appbrain App Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) seemed most promising and it delivered better results, but partly. It shows discounted apps separately when you filter by *Price Reduced*, (which is a huge improvement on PS) and assigns rankings (not related to discounts). But it doesn't give filtering choices to go by "categories" or "discount amounts", which means if I am looking for a key board app bargain as an example, I still have to trawl through all screens manually or if I am bargain hunting and want to buy an app based on discount compared to original price, I can't

**Question**

Is there a way to view discounted apps by discount percentage or category in either Google Play Store or in alternative app markets and  preferrably  purchase through existing credentials on Play Store?